# Cv2=cv2.VidioCapture=(0) does not open up vidio window. Camera turns on

Tags: python, opencv

So this code should open up the live video stream window, but it does not. I am running Windows 10 with Python 3.7 and running the code both in Pycharm and Visual Studio and see the same issue.

```
import cv2

# load yolo
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow = ('Image', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: You have to add cam.release() at the end

Answer (score 0):

Does it throw any error or is it just not showing the webcam output at all?
If its the latter than the code below will fix it.

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('webcam', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```